# Domain name verification on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I've developed an app using Firebase database and hosting and after I've bought domain name on names.co.uk (2 days ago). I've added two TXT Records as Firebase asks, but still this message shows :

```
Current Status: The TXT Records at your DNS Provider do not match the values below.
```

Does anybody know is it fine and I just need to wait more time or I've done smth wrong and this can be a reason why verification takes so long time?

[image: This is how it looks like in my control panel]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it looks like you've put your TXT records on `tennispredictions.eu.tennispredictions.eu` - every DNS host is different and it seems yours requires you to leave the first box blank to put a TXT record on the root domain:

`dig -t txt +noall +answer tennispredictions.eu.tennispredictions.eu`

If you just remove everything from the first text boxes on lines 3 and 4 you should be all set.

Comment: Now it asks for adding CNAME and asks host : *.tennispredictions.eu. Do I need to put just * ?

Comment: yup, just a `*` will apply to all subdomains and allows Firebase Hosting to ensure `random.tennispredictions.eu` gets redirected to your actual site. This step is optional if you have other content on different subdomains that you want to manage yourself

Comment: Has anyone got it working for Gandi? Do you use @ to denote the root domain? I.e. @ 10800 IN TXT "globalsign-domain-verification=keyhere

Answer (score 21):

The Firebase Hosting servers run what is essentially this command for verifying the TXT records for your domain:

```
dig -t txt +noall +answer tennispredictions.eu
```

If I run this command right now, I get no results. If the Firebase servers are seeing the same in their DNS query, they will not be able to continue.

You can also use mxtoolbox to query the DNS: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3atennispredictions.eu&run=toolpage. That also gives me no results at the moment.

That means that either you didn't save/apply your changes yet, or they haven't propagated everywhere yet. The longer it takes for the changes to show up, the more likely it becomes that you still need to take some action at your DNS provider (names.co.uk in your case).

Comment: Thanks for answer,Frank!

Comment: Sorry, we were unable to verify your domain. Eventually this message showed up :(

Comment: When I run the `dig` now, only one `TXT` record shows up and it's not one of the records in your screenshot.

Comment: is any difference between domains tennispredictions.eu or https://tennispredictions.eu?

Comment: The `https://` part is not part of your domain name, so it doesn't matter for the DNS entries. I don't know what could be the cause of your problem, but as long as the `dig` command doesn't show the TXT records, they haven't been applied properly or haven't propagated yet and the Firebase process can't continue. This [page with installation instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1389595?hl=en) might be helpful, although it looks like you have followed them.