# Firebase Hosting: We couldn't verify your domain example.com. Please check your settings and try again

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I tried to add my custom domain to firebase hosting. But firebase can not verify. Though I add txt record in my domain control panel. Here is the the
[image: Screenshoot of DNS Management after Adding a Text Record]

Comment: If I run `dig -t txt +noall +answer bolaigbe.com`, nothing shows up. So it looks like your DNS changes haven't propagated yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251969/domain-name-verification-on-firebase/36252044#36252044

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979673/unable-to-verify-custom-domain-with-firebase-using-namecheap/33984650

Answer (score 73):

[image]

> Remove your domain name and Add  @ instead of your domain.

Answer (score 44):

**For future reference replace host with `@` instead of `example.com`.** (for godaddy, namecheap, 1and1 ...)

Firebase help :

> Value for host names may differ based on each DNS provider. For example, some DNS providers use '@' for your root domain name. For subdomains, it could be 'www' or 'www.domain.com'

Comment: I have searched this for last 1 week..... I have changed, Let see what if this is work.

Comment: True not only for godaddy

Comment: Using @ solved it for namecheap

Answer (score 20):

Here's the steps I'd use:

1. DNS registrar / records host: delete TXT records pointing to firebase.
2. firebase console: delete the custom domain.
3. firebase console: add custom domain.
4. copy the two A records from firebase to DNS host

   - DNS record host may take @ for the "host" rather than "example.com" or "www.example.com"
5. save A records in DNS host
6. if DNS host has an SPF TXT record add "v=spf1 include:_spf.firebasemail.com" before the "~all" and without the quotes; I don't suggest deleting this record if already there, just add to it.
7. wait 24-48 hours to see if the changes work
8. if it doesn't work, contact firebase support from the console; be sure to take screen shots of the DNS records and the firebase console. These will help the firebase support team to troubleshoot the problem.

NOTE: I'd use [Frank's info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251969/domain-name-verification-on-firebase/36252044#36252044) to check if the site is propagating and to check what it returns. If the firebase spf info is missing, see step 6.

NOTE 1: I also don't know why it's necessary to add the firebase spf record if you're using a non-google email provider. My understanding was that SPF is for email. But, adding it helped me with 2 websites that weren't propagating.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Also - do not forget to take into account recommendations from firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain): 
"Important: For your custom domain, if your DNS records have A records or CNAME records that point to other providers, Firebase is unable to provision an SSL certificate."
For me personally, CNAME records were giving a headache, as the status shifted from "pending" to "needs setup". 

(I was connecting godaddy dns with firebase)

Comment: I just deleted the custom domain. When I try to add it again it tells me that the name is unavailable. Is it about time to properly propagate the action?

Comment: i followed and now firebase is not allow me to add the domain any more

Comment: After removing some default existing A records and C records in Godaddy worked for me.

Comment: It still says "Need setup" after even adding A records

Answer (score 10):

Be patient. It can take up to 24 hours to propagate.